Can't log into ssh via Apache Camel
I've inherited a project using Apache Camel to transfer files via SFTP
from(fromFtpUrl)
.to("file:/Users/sa/myfolder?doneFileName=${file:name}.done");

when I try to sftp into localhost (mac and ubuntu) using password authentication
    fromFtpUrl = "sftp://localhost:22/myproject?username=sa&useUserKnownHostsFile=false&StrictHostKeyChecking=no&doneFileName=done&delete=true&streamDownload=true&delay=6000&password=RAW(mypassword)";

It's apparently unable to negotiate a Kex Algorithm  (although it has no problem connection when connecting via ssh manually).  The exception is:
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot connect to sftp://anonymous@localhost:22
 Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchAlgoNegoFailException: Algorithm negotiation fail: algorithmName="server_host_key" 

When I try to ssh in using public key authentication
    fromFtpUrl = "sftp://localhost:22/myproject?username=sa&useUserKnownHostsFile=false&StrictHostKeyChecking=no&doneFileName=done&delete=true&streamDownload=true&delay=6000&privateKeyFile=/Users/sa/.ssh/id_rsa";

It's unable to read the file although the user has read/write permissions for that file (and public key authentication works via manual ssh). The exception is:
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot connect to sftp://sa@localhost:22 
 Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/kryan/Downloads/id_rsa (No such file or directory) 

Password based authentication works if I connect to an external ubuntu ssh/sftp server, but not when I connect o localhost ssh server on Mac or ubuntu 20.02 openssh.
Can I configure Camel/Jsch to get past these errors?

"...FileNotFoundException: /Users/kryan/Downloads/id_rsa" Are you sure you specified the path to the key file correctly when you got this error?

Yes, I triple checked the file exists exactly as shown with world read/write perms, so I have no idea why there is a problem opening that file

Well, somehow the command that you claim to have run specifies /Users/sa/.ssh/id_rsa, but the error message specifies /Users/kryan/Downloads/id_rsa.

I forgot to change all folder references to sa in the question, that's all

What is the permission of the private key file and of the .ssh folder? If it's too open it will also not work. Private key file has to be 600 while directory has to be 700
